# is the Raspbian NTFS implementation journaled?

Tags: raspbian, filesystem, ntfs

I read somewhere that Raspbian NTFS implementation is not journaled, but I didn't find confirmation that it is true.

If it is true there is a way to have it journaled?

I'm using it on a USB stick for Windows compatibility on my Pi Zero.

If it is not true I'd use ext4 instead to prevent corruption due to sudden power loss.

Answer (score 1):

Raspbian does not have a NTFS implementation, this is the Debian implementation, which AFAIK is common across most Linux distributions.

It is my understanding the this is not journaled, as it is a reverse engineered implementation of proprietary Microsoft code. Indeed the default NTFS driver does not even implement NTFS write.

If you want confirmation try https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm currently using it writing, anyway I'll try to ask at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

`ntfs-3g` has a limited support for journal: it will try to clear the existing entries before mounting (thus allowing you to mount a partition which was not unmounted cleanly), but it will not create new journal entries when you write on an already mounted volume.

One more reason to always unmount NTFS disks before disconnecting them from the RPi.